# Retrieving the a href value from a sublist LI tag

Tags: jquery, html

```
<li class="selected_item">
  <a class="aClass" href="#"></a>
  <ul style="display: block;">
        <li>
          <a href="aURL1"> urlText </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="aURL2"> urlText </a>
        </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

### question:

- how do i retrieve the **aURL1** that is available in the first **LI** list when the base **LI** tag has **class** set to **selected_item** dynamically?
- Is it mandatory to either have a **class** or an **ID** associated with the HTML elements in order to retrieve them using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO is yes, it's most likely mandatory to have either class or id for your element since it's definitely will make your code easier to maintain as well as helping you to target your HTML elements much more better and accurately if your page become more and more complex later on.

In your case, you can use **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** or **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** to get the href attribute of your anchor:

```
var href = $('.selected_item ul li a').attr('href'); // or .prop('href')
```

Comment: unable to accept all 3 answers which are exactly what i needed. chose the one with a clarification on the class and id for the html elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below to retrieve the href

```
var url = $('.selected_item ul a').attr('href')
```

It is not mandatory to have class/ID, but it is easier to create a selector if you have them, but you should have some way to know which element to target like an attribute value, elements position etc

Answer (score 0):

may be like this

```
var url = $('.selected_item ul li a:first').attr('href');
```

here `a:first` will select the first a

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/3WeB7/)

Comment: the fiddle link makes it much easier to understand.